# How do I keep VSCode from folding past the same indentation level

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, folding

In the gif I've attached you can see that if I fold on line 136 it keeps the blank line and you still see the next aligned section. If I fold at line 146, it swallows the next section even though they have the same alignment. What is different between the two that would cause this?

I have been googling this every time it comes up for over a year and never found a complete solution. Any help would be appreciated.

[Gif of behavior (Imgur)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T22V0.jpg)